# Exclude element from CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple navigation bar. When I hover over one of the items, I animate a line growing underneath it. Now, one of these items in my navigation bar also has a drop down menu. When I hover over those items, they too get underlined. I don't want this, but I'm not sure how to stop it. I tried the not selector, but it didn't do anything. Here's my html and css.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
      <li id="projectdropbox"><a>Projects <span class="carrot"></span></a>
        <div id="projectlist">
            <ul>
              <li><a>Cydeon World</a></li>
              <li><a>PlasmaModz</a></li>
              <li><a>Future "Ping" Pong</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS(I want to exclude these for my drop down):

```
nav ul li > a {
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li > a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.0625em;
    bottom: -0.125em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s    ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

nav ul li > a:hover:before {
     visibility: visible;
     -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
     transform: scaleX(1);  
}
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: What about you gave us all the relevant CSS, or even better, a jsfiddle with all the relevant bits?

Comment: Sure. Sorry. Give me a second.

Comment: Here. I'll try to remove anything unnecessary too: http://jsfiddle.net/npF2w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure this is what you want, but to apply some style only to the first level and not the second, use stricter selectors.

Instead of `nav ul li > a`, use `nav > ul > li > a`. So you have only children, not further descendants.

Comment: See, I thought that would work, because it would only use direct children, and not my nth-child later in my div. For whatever reason, I tried it again and this time it worked. Not sure what was different. Thanks!